# Reopen question on Anapanasati

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Following question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2533) is marked as too broad but it is not. It asks for additional instructions on Anapana if it is covered else where which is specific and limited to the one question.

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: I edited it. Is it a good edit (i.e. do you want to change or roll back that edit before reopening)? Also do you really want the [tag:vipassana] tag on that question? How about deleting that tag and replacing it with a [tag:reference-request] tag?

Comment: The editing was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reopened it.